# Execute animation function in an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a doughnut chart that loads the animation on page load. I'm trying to get the animation to run when the user scrolls into the div. I have this code block for that at the beginning of my javascript file

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var hT = $('#token-stats').offset().top,
        hH = $('#token-stats').outerHeight(),
        wH = $(window).height(),
        wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    console.log((hT - wH), wS);
    if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
        alert('pie!');
        drawDoughnutChart();
        $(window).off('scroll')
    }
});
```

I called the function inside the if statement, but it doesn't seem to work. Here's a fiddle with the exact code I'm using https://jsfiddle.net/cmLkbq6e/

the alert works fine, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(index):129 Uncaught ReferenceError: drawDoughnutChart is not defined` apparently you do not have a function called `drawDoughnutChart `

Comment: (index):129 Uncaught ReferenceError: drawDoughnutChart is not defined <-- read the console!

Comment: I use the function drawPieSegments which is defined and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a scoping issue.

Wrap the donut chart draw in its own function `drawDoughnotChart()` outside of the jQuery ready function and simply call it from your jQuery ready function.  This way drawDoughnutChart() is within scope of your `$(window).scroll` event handler.  Also to ensure only one chart is displayed, precede the chart initializer with `$("#doughnutChart").empty()`.

```
function drawDoughnutChart() {

    $("#doughnutChart").empty();

    $("#doughnutChart").drawDoughnutChart([
    { title: "test",         value : 43,  color: "#e65c53" },
    { title: "test", value:  29,   color: "#26a3b1" },
    { title: "test",      value:  21,   color: "#19818d" },
    { title: "test",        value : 3.5,   color: "#396b7e" },
    { title: "test",        value : 3.5,   color: "#a5a5a5" }
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works! I updated the fiddle. Only thing is the chart is loaded then when scrolled upon it loads it again.

Comment: If you only want the chart to load on scroll, just remove the function call from the ready function. (I updated the answer to suit).  You might also want to think about what should happen after the chart is scrolled away, and whether you want it to reload the chart or leave it as is.

Comment: @atlas24 If the code works for you, you might want to consider marking it as answered ;)

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Click the check mark next to the answer that worked for you.

Comment: After looking at your profile, you might want to go back to your previous questions on SO and do the same ;)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to store the `doughnutChart` distance relative to the top of the page (so you know when to show the chart)

Then create an event listener which will run when the user scrolls.

Lastly, create an `if` statement checking if the current window distance is greater than or equal to the `doughnutChart` distance then run your animation!

```
const doughnutChart = document.querySelector('.chart').offsetTop;

function checkScroll () {
    if (window.scrollY >= doughnutChart) {
      $("#doughnutChart").drawDoughnutChart([
        { title: "test",         value : 43,  color: "#e65c53" },
        { title: "test", value:  29,   color: "#26a3b1" },
        { title: "test",      value:  21,   color: "#19818d" },
        { title: "test",        value : 3.5,   color: "#396b7e" },
        { title: "test",        value : 3.5,   color: "#a5a5a5" }
      ]);

      // remove listener so scroll doesn't create many charts
      removeEventListener('scroll', checkScroll);
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll);
```